# DAYOFYEAR function returns different day of years

Tags: mysql, sql

First query returns 72 value and second query returns 71:

```
SELECT DAYOFYEAR('2020-03-12');


SELECT DAYOFYEAR('1990-03-12');
```

why this happened?

Comment: 2020 is a leap year, 1990 wasn't.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because well, it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2020 is a leap year. 1990 isn't. In 2020 Feb had 29 days. In 1990 there were only 28.